# JclDebug not including line numbers

Tags: delphi

I just recently upgraded from Delphi 7 to Delphi 10.1 Berlin and got jedi vcl 2.8 installed. Failed to installed for 32-bit (bcc32.exe not found) but was successful for 64-bit but that's another issue.

I am using jclDebug to capture error messages and I am using it according to: https://blog.gurock.com/working-with-delphis-new-exception-stacktrace.

```
unit StackTrace;

interface

uses
SysUtils, Classes, JclDebug;

implementation

function GetExceptionStackInfoProc(P: PExceptionRecord): Pointer;
var
  LLines: TStringList;
  LText: String;
  LResult: PChar;
begin
  LLines := TStringList.Create;
  try
    JclLastExceptStackListToStrings(LLines, True, True, True, True);
    LText := LLines.Text;
    LResult := StrAlloc(Length(LText));
    StrCopy(LResult, PChar(LText));
    Result := LResult;
  finally
    LLines.Free;
  end;
end;

function GetStackInfoStringProc(Info: Pointer): string;
begin
  Result := string(PChar(Info));
end;

procedure CleanUpStackInfoProc(Info: Pointer);
begin
  StrDispose(PChar(Info));
end;

initialization
// Start the Jcl exception tracking and register our Exception
// stack trace provider.
if JclStartExceptionTracking then
begin
  Exception.GetExceptionStackInfoProc := GetExceptionStackInfoProc;
  Exception.GetStackInfoStringProc := GetStackInfoStringProc;
  Exception.CleanUpStackInfoProc := CleanUpStackInfoProc;
  JCLdebug.JclStackTrackingOptions:=[stStack, stRawMode]; // I added this hoping it would help.
end;

finalization
// Stop Jcl exception tracking and unregister our provider.
if JclExceptionTrackingActive then
begin
  Exception.GetExceptionStackInfoProc := nil;
  Exception.GetStackInfoStringProc := nil;
  Exception.CleanUpStackInfoProc := nil;
  JclStopExceptionTracking;
end;
end.
```

When I catch an exception I log it to this method

```
procedure TLoggerForDynacViews.Log(sLog:wideString; ExceptObj:TObject = nil; displayErrorCaught : Boolean = true);
        var myFile: TextFile;
        sFile : String;
        StrList: TStringList;
        companyId : String;
    begin

      try
        sFile := Globals.LogFileName;
        try
          companyId := Store.CompanyId;
        except
          companyId := 'N/A';
        end;
        try

          AssignFile(myFile, sFile);
          if (FileExists(sFile)) then
            Append(myFile)
          else
            Rewrite(myFile);

          WriteLn(myFile, companyId + ' ('+ExcelApp.Caption +')');
          if (ExceptObj <> nil) then begin
            try
              StrList := TStringList.Create;
              StrList.Add(Format('{ Original Exception - %s }', [Exception(ExceptObj).Message]));
              StrList.Add(Exception(ExceptObj).StackTrace);
              StrList.Add('{ _______End of the exception stact trace block_______ }');
              StrList.Add(' ');
              if displayErrorCaught then
                ShowMessage('Error has been caught.  See DynacViews->About->Log File for details.');
              WriteLn(myFile, FormatDateTime('c',Now) + ' - ' + StrList.Text);
              Exit;
            finally
              StrList.Free;
            end;
          end;


          WriteLn(myFile, FormatDateTime('c',Now) + ' - ' + sLog);
        finally
          CloseFile(myFile);
        end;
      except

      end;
    end;
```

But I am not getting line numbers.  In Delphi 7 I was getting very useful output but with the latest delphi and jcldebug I am getting helpful but not as nearly has helpful as it could be.

```
12/09/2016 11:59:55 AM - { Original Exception - Access violation at address  0000000012D60027 in module 'DynacViews2b.dll'. Read of address 000000000000002A  }
(00000000006F1E1D){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E62E1D]  JclDebug._ZN8Jcldebug17TJclStackInfoListC3EbiPvbS1_S1_ + $10D
(00000000006F19F8){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E629F8]   JclDebug._ZN8Jcldebug18JclCreateStackListEbiPvbS0_ + $48
(00000000006F1909){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E62909] JclDebug._ZN8Jcldebug21DoExceptionStackTraceEPN6System7TObjectEPvbS3_ + $79
(00000000006F3233){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E64233] JclDebug._ZN8Jcldebug14DoExceptNotifyEPN6System7TObjectEPvbS3_ + $93
(00000000006E4B85){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E55B85] JclHookExcept._ZN13Jclhookexcept13TNotifierItem8DoNotifyEPN6System7TObjectEPvbS4_ + $35
(00000000006E4DCC){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E55DCC] JclHookExcept._ZN13Jclhookexcept14DoExceptNotifyEPN6System7TObjectEPvbS3_ + $BC
(00000000006E4F1E){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E55F1E] JclHookExcept._ZN13Jclhookexcept20HookedRaiseExceptionEjjjPNS_19TExceptionArgumentsE + $6E
(000000000000EBB6){DynacViews2b.dll} [000000001277FBB6] System._ZN6System14_RaiseAtExceptEPNS_7TObjectEPv + $106
(000000000000EBE1){DynacViews2b.dll} [000000001277FBE1] System._ZN6System12_RaiseExceptEPNS_7TObjectE + $11
(0000000000166164){DynacViews2b.dll} [00000000128D7164] System.Win.ComObj._ZN6System3Win6Comobj19DispatchInvokeErrorEiRK12tagEXCEPINFO + $C4
(0000000000165BA5){DynacViews2b.dll} [00000000128D6BA5] System.Win.ComObj._ZN6System3Win6Comobj14DispatchInvokeENS_15DelphiInterfaceI9IDispatchEEPNS_9TCallDescEPNS_11StaticArrayIiLi65536EEEPvPNS_7VariantE + $275
(0000000000166087){DynacViews2b.dll} [00000000128D7087] System.Win.ComObj._ZN6System3Win6Comobj13VarDispInvokeEPNS_7VariantERKS2_PNS_9TCallDescEPv + $B7
(000000000005162E){DynacViews2b.dll} [00000000127C262E] System.Variants._ZN6System8Variants14DispInvokeCoreEP8TVarDataRKS1_PNS_9TCallDescEPv + $BE
(0000000000051731){DynacViews2b.dll} [00000000127C2731] System.Variants._ZN6System8Variants11_DispInvokeEP8TVarDataRKS1_PNS_9TCallDescE + $41
(000000000071A595){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E8B595] ExcelWrapperTypes._ZN17Excelwrappertypes25TCustomDocumentProperties8GetValueEN6System13UnicodeStringERKNS1_7VariantE + $75
(000000000071A7D8){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E8B7D8] ExcelWrapperTypes._ZN17Excelwrappertypes25TCustomDocumentProperties9GetStringEN6System13UnicodeStringES2_ + $78
(0000000000692BFF){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E03BFF] StoreClasses._ZN12Storeclasses8TStorage23loadCustomDocumentPropsEN6System15DelphiInterfaceIN12Excelwrapper9IWorkbookEEE + $72F
(0000000000720329){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E91329] DynacViewForBook._ZN16Dynacviewforbook17TDynacViewForBook14GetViewForBookEN6System15DelphiInterfaceIN9Excel20009_WorkbookEEEb + $69
(0000000000728978){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E99978] AddinMenu._ZN9Addinmenu20TColumnTemplatesMenuC3EPN8Adxaddin19TadxCommandBarPopupEU9__closurePFvN6System13UnicodeStringEE + $E8
(000000000072867A){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E9967A] AddinMenu._ZN9Addinmenu11TColumnMenuC3EPN8Adxaddin15TadxContextMenuEU9__closurePFvN6System13UnicodeStringEE + $13A
(00000000007258DE){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012E968DE] AddinMenu._ZN9Addinmenu11TDynacMenus9BuildMenuEU9__closurePFvN6System13UnicodeStringEE + $9E
(000000000075CB3C){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012ECDB3C] DynacViewBook._ZN13Dynacviewbook14TDynacViewBook13BuildMainMenuEv + $8C
(0000000000740B02){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012EB1B02] DynacViewBook._ZN13Dynacviewbook14TDynacViewBook18OnWorkbookActivateEv + $6F2
(00000000007CE499){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012F3F499] DynacViews2b_IMPL._ZN17Dynacviews2b_impl12TAddInModule18OnWorkbookActivateEPN6System7TObjectENS1_15DelphiInterfaceIN9Excel20009_WorkbookEEE + $49
(00000000005A79DA){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012D189DA] adxHostAppEvents._ZN16Adxhostappevents18TadxExcelAppEvents11InvokeEventEiRN6System12DynamicArrayINS1_10OleVariantEEE + $A2A
(00000000005A0CC1){DynacViews2b.dll} [0000000012D11CC1] adxHostAppEvents._ZN16Adxhostappevents17TadxEventDispatch6InvokeEiRK5_GUIDitPvS4_S4_S4_ + $151
(00000000002CE49D){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F9EF49D] Unknown function at  + $2CF49D
(00000000002CE2E6){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F9EF2E6] Unknown function at  + $2CF2E6
(000000000017BA40){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F89CA40] Unknown function at  + $17CA40
(0000000000120138){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F841138] Unknown function at  + $121138
(000000000011FB65){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F840B65] Unknown function at  + $120B65
(000000000011F95F){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F84095F] Unknown function at  + $12095F
(0000000000129B75){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F84AB75] Unknown function at  + $12AB75
(00000000000E0BD0){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F801BD0] Unknown function at  + $E1BD0
(000000000006B44A){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F78C44A] Unknown function at  + $6C44A
(0000000000EB6035){EXCEL.EXE   } [00000001405D7035] Unknown function at LinkASPPModelTable + $3F60E5
(0000000000BA53BD){EXCEL.EXE   } [00000001402C63BD] Unknown function at LinkASPPModelTable + $E546D
(00000000000587D5){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F7797D5] Unknown function at  + $597D5
(00000000000BE448){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F7DF448] Unknown function at  + $BF448
(0000000000019484){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F73A484] Unknown function at  + $1A484
(00000000000F1D01){EXCEL.EXE   } [000000013F812D01] Unknown function at  + $F2D01
(00000000000149BD){kernel32.dll} [00000000779E59BD] BaseThreadInitThunk + $D
(00000000000292E1){ntdll.dll   } [0000000077C1A2E1] RtlUserThreadStart + $21
```

While the above is helpful I really miss the line numbers.

For my project Debug Information is true and include remote debug symbols.  I am not sure what properties need to be set.

**Edit:**  Issue appears to be due to my map file not having line numbers in it.
My delphi 7 map file has many :

```
Line numbers for DynacViewBook(DynacViewBook.pas) segment .text
```

But I have none of these in my Delphi 10.1 map file.

Here is my options for linking [delphi linker options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tplky.png)

Comment: Doesn't this come from the map file. Does yours have line numbers. If you are prepared to pay for Delphi you may as well fork out the small sum needed to get madExcept,  the tool of choice.

Comment: Funny thing is my delphi 7 with jcldebug has line numbers.  I don't think my delphi 7 project is set to produce a map file.  I'll have to test that.

Comment: Where is it going to get the mapping between code address and line number other than the map file?

Comment: I compiled with a detailed map option and I still don't get line numbers.

Comment: Did you look at the map file. How are you feeding that info to jcl debug.

Comment: No idea as I am not a delphi guru by any means or very familiar with the delphi IDE. I do have a map file in my Delphi 7 folder but it is not set in  the options so I think I might be compiling with an out of date map file for my delphi 7 project.

Comment: So the map file created by Delphi 7 has line numbers in it but the map file created by Delphi 10.1 does not.  I must be missing an option.  I choose detailed for map.  I assumed that would do the trick.

Comment: I think you need to look in the linker options.

Comment: Still I'd heartily recommend madExcept

Comment: Looking at your image you also need debug info in the compiler options

Answer (score 2):

So I finally figured it out.  Part of the problem when I migrated from Delphi 7 to Delphi 10.1 was I did not ensure that my compiling and linking options transferred correctly.  I made an assumption that the settings were correct.

The reason I was missing linking information was I needed in the compiling options **Use Debug .DCU's** to see my own pas files and **Local Symbols** to see the delphi pas files along with **Debug Information**.

I had to delete my .dcu's and re-compile before the line information appeared.

Edit:  Strange thing is the mapping file contains the name

```
DynacViewBook.TDynacViewBook.OnWorkbookActivate
```

and

```
DynacViewBook.$pdata$_ZN13Dynacviewbook14TDynacViewBook18OnWorkbookActivateEv
```

And the StackTrace contains the ugly method not the pretty method name. My delphi 7 map file does not contain any ugly names.

Even the delphi debug information is ugly names.  Must be a setting.

Comment: hehe - you keep pushing.  I feel like it is something else.  I have both names but for some reason the ugly name is used.  Might be a JclDebug option at this point.